# extract data from 9pm the previous day to 9pm of current day in DB2

Tags: db2

how can we extract data from 9pm the previous day up until  9pm of  current day using a timestamp column in DB2, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work but I'm not at a machine to test it right now...

```
WHERE datefield BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY, '21:00:00')
                    AND TIMESTAMP(CURRENT DATE, '21:00:00')
```